# How to save canvas to an image object?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, html5-canvas

How to save the content of the canvas to an image object? Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `var imgUrl = myCanvas.toDataUrl();`

Comment: Note, however, that this technique may throw a security exception if the image came from another domain. See the example at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-url/.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/). [Canvas2Png](http://flashcanvas.net/docs/usage) claims to be more cross-browser.

toDataUrl() will not work in Internet Explorer.

Also, if you truly want cross-browser functionality with the canvas, make sure to use [Excanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/)